# How to reload selected cell in particular section for expand/collapse in tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, expandablelistview

I am doing expand/collapse tableview cells feature in my iOS app. I have multiple sections. And each section has multiple cells. By default, cell height is 100, once user taps on cell, I am increasing height to 200.

So, Based on Bool value, I am changing it. But, While scrolling tableview, It is interchanging the expanded/collapse cells in between sections.
Like if I tap on first section first cell, It is expanding, but after scrolling tableview, Second section first cell also expanding.

My Requirement is, If user tap on particular cell, that cell only should expand/collapse. User can manually expand and close. User can expand multiple cells.

So, I have tried to store Indexpath row and Section.

```
         var expandedIndexSet : IndexSet = []
             var expandedIndexSection : IndexSet = []
         
             func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellIdentifier", for:
         indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
         
if expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row) && expandedIndexSection.contains(indexPath.section) { // expanded true
                     cell.height = 200
                    //some other data loading here
                 }
                 else {  //expanded false
              cell.height = 100
                 }
              }
         
             @IBAction moreButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
                 
                 if(expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row)) && expandedIndexSection.contains(indexPath.section){
                     expandedIndexSet.remove(indexPath.row)
                     expandedIndexSection.remove(indexPath.section)
                     
                 } else {
                     expandedIndexSet.insert(indexPath.row)
                     expandedIndexSection.insert(indexPath.section)
                 }
                 entriesTableView.beginUpdates()
                 entriesTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                 entriesTableView.endUpdates()
             }
```

Anyone can give better approach than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store section and row independently in separate arrays, your algorithm will fail.
The reason is that both are dependent:
Think of three expanded cells (row:1, section:1), (row:2, section:1), (row:3, section:2)

Now what happens for the cell (row:3, section:1)?
The row-array contains the value "3", and the section-array contains value "1", therefore it will be considered as expanded.

Therefore, you need to store the index path as a whole - see the sample code:

```
var expanded:[IndexPath] = []

expanded.append(IndexPath(row:1, section:1))
expanded.append(IndexPath(row:2, section:1))
expanded.append(IndexPath(row:3, section:2))

let checkPath = IndexPath(row:3, section:1)
if (expanded.contains(checkPath)) {
    print ("is expanded")
} else {
    print ("collapsed")
}
```

### Update

So in your button handle, you'll do the following:

```
@IBAction moreButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if(expanded.contains(indexPath)) {
        expanded.removeAll { (checkPath) -> Bool in
            return checkPath == indexPath
        }
    } else {
        expanded.append(indexPath)
    }
    entriesTableView.beginUpdates()
    entriesTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    entriesTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion @AndreasOetjen, But in button action how can I insert and remove expanded indexpath?

Comment: Check my updated answer - I don't know how you get the index path that corresponds to the button, but somehow you seem to store it.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting indexpath from button tag, This code working fine, and it is better approach than my code. Thank you @AndreasOetjen I accepted your answer and upvoted too

Comment: any suggestions for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420575/how-to-handle-open-all-close-all-in-tableview-cell-with-each-cell-has-view-more I have to show open all/close all