# How to handle open all/close all in tableview cell with each cell has View More/View less options in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, expandablelistview

I am doing Swift project, there it has **view more/view less** option for each cell. I have did it with following code. And it was for for View more/View less options.

> //ViewController Class
>
> ```
> var expanded:[IndexPath] = []
>
> //Custom protocol
>
>     func viewMoreTapped(cell: tableviewcell) {
>         
>         let indexpath = EntriesTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
>         let indexPath = IndexPath(item: indexpath!.row, section: indexpath!.section)
>         if(expanded.contains(indexPath)) {
>             expanded.removeAll { (checkPath) -> Bool in
>                 return checkPath == indexPath
>             }
>         } else {
>             expanded.append(indexPath)
>         }
>         entriesTableView.beginUpdates()
>         entriesTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
>         entriesTableView.endUpdates()
>     }
>
> @IBAction func expandAllBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
>     
>     isExpandedAll = !isExpandedAll
>     expandAllButton.titlelabel.text = isExpandedAll ? "Open All" : "Close All"
>     self.entriesTableView.reloadData()
> }
>
>
>         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
>                  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellIdentifier", for:
>          indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
>         let checkPath = IndexPath(row:indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
>         if expanded.contains(checkPath) {
>             cell.cellConfigure(index: indexPath.row, isexpanded: true, info: Info, expandedAll: isExpandedAll)
>         } else {
>             cell.cellConfigure(index: indexPath.row, isexpanded: false, info: Info, expandedAll: isExpandedAll)
>         }
>
>     return cell
>
> }
>
> //Tableview cell class
>
>     var isExpanded: Bool = false
>
>     func cellConfigure(index: Int, isexpanded : Bool, info: Info, expandedAll: Bool) {
>
> //For open all/close all handling
>       if expandedAll && isExpanded == false {
>             isExpanded = true
>             viewMoreBtn.titleLabel?.text = "View Less"
>         } else  {
>             viewMoreBtn.titleLabel?.text = isExpanded ? "View Less" : "View More"
>         }
>   //view more/view less handling               cellHeight.constant = isExpanded ? 40 : 120
>
> }
>
>     @IBAction func viewMoreBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
>         
>         isExpanded = !isExpanded
>         delegate?.viewMoreTapped(cell: self) // this is custom protocol
>     }
> ```

It is working fine for each cell **View more/View less**, But after user taps on **open all**,  it should be open all cells and each cell if user has taps on **view less**, it should be close selected cell only. But, it's not working that time.

The requirement is

1. if user taps on **view more**, it should be open selected cell. If user taps on **view less**, it should be close selected cell.
2. Also if user taps on **open all**, All cells should be expanded, and also same time if user tap on view less for particular cell, that time only selected cell should be close.
3. If user taps on close all, all cells should be close and if user taps on view less while close all showing, only selected cell should be close.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Rather than using an array of `IndexPath` I would use a `Set<IndexPath>`. Then adding a removing a given index path from the set is efficient and simple as is checking for the presence of a given index path.

Comment: Here my issue is, How to handle expand all/ collapse all

Comment: Collapse all is simple; just remove all of the elements from the set and reload the tableview. Expand all is much the same, except you need a loop to insert all of the index paths into the set and then reload the tableview. I would suggest that you don't toggle the `isExpanded` directly in the cell. Let the view controller set it and have a `didSet` on the property to change the cell appearance.

Comment: Can you post your answer if possible, I am bit confusing here, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `IndexSet` to track the expanded rows; It is easier to insert, remove and check for the presence of index paths using a set.

To collapse all of the rows you can simply remove all of the elements from the set.  To expand all you insert all index paths into the set.

You haven't provided detail on how your table data is stored.  For the purposes of my answer I am going to use an array of arrays called `data` -  The outer array is the sections and each inner array are the rows in that section.  ie `numberOfSections` is `data.count` and the number of rows in a section is `data[indexPath.section].count`

**View Controller**

```
var expanded = [IndexSet]()

//Custom protocol


func loadData() {
    // After data is fetched
    self.expanded = Array(repeating: IndexSet(),count:data.count)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func viewMoreTapped(cell: tableviewcell) {
        
   guard let indexPath = entriesTableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
       return
   }

   let row = indexPath.row
   let section = indexPath.section

   if self.expanded[section].contains(row) {
       self.expanded[section].remove(row) 
   } else {
       self.expanded[section].insert(row)
   }

   self.entriesTableView.beginUpdates()
   self.entriesTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
   self.entriesTableView.endUpdates()
}

@IBAction func expandAllBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    isExpandedAll.toggle()
    expandAllButton.titlelabel.text = isExpandedAll ? "Open All" : "Close All"
    
    if isExpandedAll {
        self.expanded = data.map { return IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<$0.count)}
    } else {
        self.expanded = Array(repeating: IndexSet(),count:data.count)
    }
    self.entriesTableView.reloadData()
}
      
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellIdentifier", for:
         indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.cellConfigure(isExpanded: self.expanded[indexPath.section].contains(indexPath.row), info: info) // A cell should never need to know its index path

    return cell
}
```

**Cell**

```
var isExpanded: Bool = false

func cellConfigure(isExpanded : Bool, info: Info) {

    viewMoreBtn.titleLabel?.text = isExpanded ? "View less":"View more"
    cellHeight.constant = isExpanded ? 40 : 120

}

@IBAction func viewMoreBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.viewMoreTapped(cell: self) // this is custom protocol
}
```

A general note, variables and functions should start with a lower case letter. Class and struct names should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulw11 for your valuable suggestions, But I have multiple tableview sections and each section has multiple rows, How can I check this array count here         self.expanded.insert(integersIn:0..<array.count) //Substitute your data source array for "array"

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to use an array of `IndexSet`; one for each section. You can then adapt my code to use the correct index set and to use a `for` loop to clear or insert indices into each set when you select/unselect all.

Comment: So, Suppose If there are 100 sections in my table, then I need to use 100 IndexSet? Is this good practice? Paulw11

Comment: Why not?  If you have 100 sections then you need to track the expansion status of the rows in those 100 sections.

Comment: But, I have tried this logic, seems not effecting, I mean its not expanding or collapse. Seems it should store Indexpath which contains Section and Row both.

Comment: Well, you can use a `Set<indexPath>` instead of `[IndexSet]`, it is just that initialising a `Set<IndexPath>` with a range of index paths isn't as easy; You need a `for` loop (or two nested `for` loops) that create each `IndexPath` and add it to the set.  I will update my answer to work with sections.